# I want to draw a chart in my apps

Tags: android

All.I want to draw a chart in my apps.I used the google's jar,but the jar too simple.Do you know some other third-party jar like this to draw a chart? it must be draw a complex 2D line chart,can control the x and y coordinate‘s value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good graphing packages for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android)

Comment: Similar questions already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271248/how-to-draw-charts-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) a try

**edit:** other nice library: [droidcharts](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/creating-charts-with-droidcharts-for-android/)

Comment: i tried,but it can not meet my needs.it can not not control the x and y coordinate‘s value.do you know some other?

Comment: I edited my answer, have you tried droidcharts? the XY xhart seems what you need